# Question about Shaft Coupling Size

Tags: machining, coupling

I'm trying to extend the crank handle on my Ryobi drill press to be able to accomodate a drill press table, similar to https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZezGyogW1qk

1. The worm gear is: https://www.powertoolreplacementparts.com/ryobi-089140314084-worm. It's diameter is 14mm.
2. The crank handle is: https://www.powertoolreplacementparts.com/ryobi-089140314085-handle-crank. It accepts a 14mm rod and has a set screw.

What I'd like to do is connect a shaft coupler to the worm gear and a 8in 14mm rod on the other end. Then connect this end of the rod to the crank handle. On Amazon, I see shaft coupler:([https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B078VRL7DY/ref=ox_sc_act_title_1?smid=A1THAZDOWP300U&psc=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B078VRL7DY))

I have a question about the size. For example what does 8-14mm? Is it each end of the coupler can acommodate a rod between 8-14mm or one end accepts a 8mm rod and the other end accepts a 14mm rod?

Comment: By extend I assume you mean away from the drill press body so the crank clears the table? Not extend the handle length which wouldn't make sense if you are trying to clear the table? Because the easy way is to just use shorter handles. In any case, that specification is telling you which size shaft the coupler can connect to on both ends. Search on McMaster-Carr for more info about what may be available and how they work.

Comment: The coupling you have there isn't rigid--it's supposed to couple two shafts, each of which is rigidly mounted, and may be misaligned. Under the circumstances, a simpler one will probably work better. https://www.amazon.com/Sinoblu-Coupling-Aluminum-Couplings-Coupler/dp/B097ZB93KX/ref=sr_1_1_sspa?crid=1O8VK67JALBF6&th=1

Comment: Thank you both. Yes, move it away from the drill press body so the handle doesn't get jammed in the table. I will look at the coupler Jerry posted.